# VBA Excel Dynamically Display Added Results

Tags: vba, user-interface, excel, dynamic

So I am modeling my question with a simple Grocery List applications.

**Program GUI:**

[image: AddMore]

Now what I want is for the Customer to enter: Eggs, Milk, and Bread and for that to enter and output to a .txt file.

**Current Code:**

```
Private Sub CreateList_Click()

Dim myFile As String, myString As String
myFile = "C:\Reformatted.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1

myString = First.Value + Second.Value + Third.Value + Fourth.Value + Fifth.Value

Print #1, myString

Close #1
Shell "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe C:\Reformatted.txt", 1

End Sub
```

**Desired Operation:**

What I want to happen is that ther enter there first 5 items. Then it prompts them if they want another 5. If they do then they can add another line.

So I understand that I can add a MsgBox in VB and just design a while loop for that. My question is how to display the results of their first/previous submissions?

**Desired Result:**

[image: DynamicDisplay]

I understand that VB stores the values as variables, but how can I show them to the user while they still have a chance to enter more entries. Also how to add all this with the preferred formatting to a notepad file?

----------------------------After Miss Palmer's Answer--------------------------

```
Private Sub AddEntry_Click()

Dim UserEntry As String

UserEntry = First.Value + DDPP.Value + Filer.Value + EntryNumber.Value

myString = myString & Chr(13) & UserEntry

GroceryList.UserDisplay.Caption = "You have entered:" & myString

End Sub
```

**Scenario 1 - First Addition**

[image: Scenario1]

**Scenario 2 - Second Addition**

[image: Scenario2]

The two additions should be placed one after the other. But currently it just replaces it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update a label on the form on each iteration of your while loop using something of the form:

```
FormName.LabelName.Caption = "you have entered:" & myString
```

and then add to the string each loop with

```
myString  = myString & First.Value + Second.Value + Third.Value + Fourth.Value + Fifth.Value
```

EDIT

```
myString  = myString & chr(13) & First.Value + Second.Value + Third.Value + Fourth.Value + Fifth.Value
```

Comment: This looks good! Quick question how can I insert a line after every entry or put every entry on its separate line?

Comment: Perfect. Last thing. I added a "Add Another Line" Button. It doesnt seem to work when I post the same item again. If I change the code it changes the line added but doesn't add to it. (I edited my question)

Comment: i think it's because every time you click the button a new instance of the sub is created and the variable is local to one instance. try making myString a global variable (declared outside the sub).

Comment: Thanks that did it! Still learning VB so didn't even know about global variables. Also you have the name of a high school teacher of mine! lol So thanks!